# RandomWalk solution issue

Tags: java, random, stddraw

**PROBLEM**

I am working on a code where I am simulating a dog walking in a city - trying to escape the city. The dog makes random choices of which way to go to at each intersection with equal probability.If stuck at a dead end the dog will come directly back to the middle of a big city and start all over again. The dog will do this again and again until it gets out of the city or until it gets tired after T number of trials. But by the time the the dog starts again from the middle(N/2,N/2) on each try, it will have forgotten all the intersections it had visited in the previous attempt.

**IDEA**

The idea is to mimic a code given in our textbook and come up with the solution. We were given input N, T - where N is the number of north-south and east-west streets in the city and T is the number of times the dog will try to get out of the city before it gives up. We have to draw it out, using StdDraw. We have been given how to make random movements - **generate  a number between 0 and 4 - up: 0    right: 1    down: 2    left: 3**

**My Approach**

```
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomWalk {
private static final Random RNG = new Random (Long.getLong ("seed", 
        System.nanoTime())); 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);    // lattice size
    int T = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);    // number of trials
    int deadEnds = 0;                     // trials resulting in a dead end

    StdDraw.setCanvasSize();
    StdDraw.setXscale(0,N);
    StdDraw.setYscale(0,N);

    // simulate T self-avoiding walks
    for (int t = 0; t < T; t++) {

        StdDraw.clear();

        StdDraw.setPenRadius(0.002);
        StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.LIGHT_GRAY);

        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            StdDraw.line(i, 0, i, N);
            StdDraw.line(0, i, N, i);
        }

        StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.RED);
        StdDraw.setPenRadius(0.01);

        boolean[][] a = new boolean[N][N];   // intersections visited 
        int x = N/2, y = N/2;                // current position



        // repeatedly take a random step, unless you've already escaped
        while (x > 0 && x < N-1 && y > 0 && y < N-1)  {
            int t_x = x;
            int t_y=y;
            // dead-end, so break out of loop
            if (a[x-1][y] && a[x+1][y] && a[x][y-1] && a[x][y+1]) {
                deadEnds++;
                break;
            } 

            // mark (x, y) as visited
            a[x][y] = true; 

            // take a random step to unvisited neighbor
            int r = RNG.nextInt(4);
            if (r ==3) {
                //move left
                if (!a[x-1][y])
                    t_x--;

            }
            else if (r == 1 ) {
                //move right
                if (!a[x+1][y])
                    t_x++;
            }
            else if (r == 2) {
                //move down
                if (!a[x][y-1])
                    t_y--;
            }
            else if (r == 0) {
              //move up
                if (!a[x][y+1])
                    t_y++;
            }

            StdDraw.line(t_x, t_y, x, y);
            x = t_x;
            y = t_y;
        } 
        System.out.println("T: "+t);
    } 
    System.out.println(100*deadEnds/T + "% dead ends");

    }
}
```

**ISSUE**

Given N - 15, T - 10, -Dseed=5463786 we should get an output like - http://postimg.org/image/s5iekbkpf/

I am getting - see http://postimg.org/image/nxipit0pp/

I don't know where I am going wrong. I know this is very specific in nature, but I am really confused so as to what I am doing wrong. I tried all 24 permutations of 0,1,2,3 but none of them gave the output desired. So, I conclude that the issue in in my code.

Comment: should work,I got :
T: 6
T: 7
T: 8
T: 9
20% dead ends

Answer (score 0):

check your StdDraw.java with:

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdDraw.java.html

your code should be fine, I got the expected result

Comment: What do you think is the problem? I do get some result, but not the one of dog walking out the city. What could be wrong?

Comment: Just making sure.

Expected : http://postimg.org/image/s5iekbkpf/
Current : http://postimg.org/image/nxipit0pp/